# Encrypt Mysql password on shell script

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

How to write the password to result_p.txt in encrypted form and how retrieve it back as well?

```
echo "Please enter the mysql root password : "
stty -echo
read PASSWORD
echo $PASSWORD > result_p.txt
stty echo
if [[ "$PASSWORD" = "amma" ]]
then
echo "Entered Mysql password is :" $PASSWORD 
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a small Python script to obfuscate it using Base64:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import getpass
password = getpass.getpass()
open("result_p.txt", "w").write(password.encode("base64"))
```

Then to read the password:

```
password = open("result_p.txt").read().decode("base64")
```

Comment: For the downboater: would you care to explain? It's not a shell script, but could easily become one: `echo $PASSWORD | python -c 'import sys; print sys.stdin.read().encode("base64")'`

Comment: How can I bring it on my shell script ?

Comment: Ok David Please see below example :[root@localhost ~]# PASSWORD="amma"
[root@localhost ~]# echo $PASSWORD | python -c 'import sys; print sys.stdin.read().encode("base64")'
Ouput is : YW1tYQo=
 Hoe can i decript it back ?

Comment: It's already a shell script, and there is a common `base64` command that will encode/decode base64. So no need to get python involved. Also, base64 is not encryption (I realize you didn't call it that, but the OP asked for encryption)

Comment: You can decode it using `echo $ENCODED | python -c 'import sys; sys.stdin.read().decode("base64")'`.

Comment: @Brenton Define “common”. As far as I can tell it's part of the GNU coreutils, but it's not on my Mac, and I don't expect it will be on BSD machines. Further, you're correct — base64 isn't “encryption”. But I'm doing a bit of reading between the lines and assuming that Arunjith just wants obfuscation.

Comment: @David Wolever, I think you suggestion is okay. For simple text gibberish for his question, base64 just serve fine. 
#!/bin/sh

echo "Please enter the mysql root password : "
read PASSWORD
echo $PASSWORD | base64 > result_p.txt
read PASSWORD < result_p.txt
PASSWORD=`echo $PASSWORD | base64 -d`
if [[ "$PASSWORD" = "amma" ]]
then
echo "Entered Mysql password is :" $PASSWORD
fi

Comment: @David Correct, it is part of coreutils, as the Question is tagged Linux I don't think BSD/OS X is relevant. No problem if this is the solution the OP is after, I just didn't think it answered the original question as asked. Hence the downvote.

Comment: David I have one more question ? How to obfuscat this password encryption and decryption shell script ? (ie I want to make the shell script in non human readable other wise some one can go through the shell script and find out the password)

Comment: @Arunjith in short, you can't. If it's in the shell script, someone would be able to read it. There may be utilities to do that sort of thing, but I don't know of one off the top of my head.

Comment: @Brenton Ah, very true. I hadn't noticed it was tagged `linux`. You are very right, then.

Comment: @Arunjith: if you've got it working fine- accept this answer! :)

Comment: Ok :) ... Better / Essential to get the script Obfuscated other wise some one having linux root password can read the script and find out the password ( As I am trying to hide the DB root password ).

Comment: @Arunjith: sorry, but this kind of "protection" is a joke. And it would be easier to recommend you something if you posted what you are trying to do in general.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that it has no sense while user can view contents of your shell script. IMHO, the most simple way would be 'chmodding' resultant *result_p.txt* so that it is not readable by regular user.